# Multiple columns referencing single table - Sails JS API Model

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js

Recently I've taken to learning Sails JS, and while it seems incredibly useful (***I don't have to build an api on my own?!***) the current little project I'm testing sails with has run into a bit of a snag.

My main profession is a teacher, and the *eventual* goal for this whole project is to have a list of students, peers who they work well with(`friend_id`), and students who they do not (`unfriend_id`). Using this information, plus their current GPA, I want to optimize the seating chart through some other algorithms.

First part, I need to get the data returned to from the Sails data server to agree with me.

What I need for sails to do (and I've looked through the sails docs at one-to-many collections as well as many-to-many and many-to-one but this problem seems particular) is to gather all of the items for a user based on the `friend_id` or `unfriend_id` column.

## Data

[This SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eefdb8/1/0) has the basic schema setup with some dummy data for everyone to copy/paste over and work with directly if needed.

### users

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_first_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `student_last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `student_home_phone` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_guardian_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_gpa` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `class_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `student_id` (`student_id`)
);
```

### relations

```
CREATE TABLE `relations` (
  `relation_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '100000',
  `friend_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unfriend_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `relation_id` (`relation_id`)
);
```

### dummy data (ignore the names)

```
INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (1,'Paul','Walker','1112223333','fake@email.com',2,1),(2,'Vin','Diesel','1112223333','fake@email.com',3,1),(3,'That','One\'Guy','1112223333','fake@email.com',4,1),(4,'Not','Yuagin','1112223333','fake@email.com',2,1),(5,'Hei','Yu','1112223333','fake@email.com',2,1);
INSERT INTO `relations` VALUES (1,1,2,NULL),(2,2,1,NULL),(3,1,NULL,4),(4,4,NULL,1),(5,1,5,NULL),(6,5,1,NULL),(7,2,3,NULL),(8,3,2,NULL);
```

I tried something like the following, but when I run this the api returns an empty json array for both (before I would at least receive a list of the students / relations depending on the api I was looking).

### Students.js

```
module.exports = {
 connection:'localMysql',
    schema: 'true',
    attributes: {
        student_id: {
            type: "integer",
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey:true
        },
        student_first_name:{
            type:'string'
        },
        student_last_name:{
            type:'string'
        },
        student_home_phone:{
            type:'integer'
        },
        student_guardian_email:{
            type: 'email'
        },
        class_id:{
            type:'integer'
        },
        friends:{
            collection:'relationship',
            via:'student_friends'
        }
    },
    autoPK: false,
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false
}
```

### Relationship.js

```
module.exports = {
    connection:'localMysql',
    tableName:'relations',

    attributes: {
        relation_id:{
            type: 'integer',
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey:true
        },
        student_id:{
            type:'integer'
        },
        friend_id:{
            type:'integer'
        },
        unfriend_id:{
            type:'integer'
        },
        student_friends:{
            collection:'students',
            via:'student_id'
        }
    },
    autoPK: false,
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false
}
```

I'm not totally new to all of what is going on right now, but I'm just new enough to Node and Sails that I just seem to be scratching my head. If what I want can't be done through the collections model, where would I place the code to make these transactions occur? I *assume* (but you know what they say ...) it would be in the `StudentsController.js` file?

## Tl;Dr

Can I get the behavior created by this MySQL query:

```
select 
    s.*, group_concat(r.friend_id) as friends, group_concat(r.unfriend_id) as unfriends 
from 
    students s  
left join 
    relations r 
ON s.student_id = r.student_id
GROUP BY s.student_id;
```

replicated using the `collection` setup in Sails JS?

If not, where do I put the code to do so by hand? (assuming it *isn't* `StudentsController.js`)

## UPDATE

following the advice of @Solarflare I've managed to get something a little bit more inline, though this is a very rough start. Now I get a column called 'relationships' but there's nothing in it. Which is better than before where I got absolutely nothing (as in all that was returned was `[]`). But it's an empty array. (the output is below).

**note:** I removed `student_friends` declaration from the Relationship model.

How do I fix that?

```
[
  {
    "relationships": [],
    "student_id": 1,
    "student_first_name": "Paul",
    "student_last_name": "Walker",
    "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
    "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
    "class_id": 1
  },
  {
    "relationships": [],
    "student_id": 2,
    "student_first_name": "Vin",
    "student_last_name": "Diesel",
    "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
    "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
    "class_id": 1
  },
  {
    "relationships": [],
    "student_id": 3,
    "student_first_name": "That",
    "student_last_name": "One'Guy",
    "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
    "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
    "class_id": 1
  },
  {
    "relationships": [],
    "student_id": 4,
    "student_first_name": "Not",
    "student_last_name": "Yuagin",
    "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
    "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
    "class_id": 1
  },
  {
    "relationships": [],
    "student_id": 5,
    "student_first_name": "Hei",
    "student_last_name": "Yu",
    "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
    "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
    "class_id": 1
  }
]
```

### UPDATE #2

Well just sort of messing around while waiting I got something very rudimentary to work. I went into the `Relationship.js` file and changed the definition of `student_id` to `model:'students',via:'student_id'` and i can at least get all of the relationships for a given student. It's giving me the correct collection, but I do still wonder if there's a more direct way to fiddle with this to get what I need. Here is the output of `localhost:1337/students` now:

```
[
  {
    "relationships": [
      {
        "relation_id": 1,
        "friend_id": 2,
        "unfriend_id": null,
        "student_id": 1
      },
      {
        "relation_id": 3,
        "friend_id": null,
        "unfriend_id": 4,
        "student_id": 1
      },
      {
        "relation_id": 5,
        "friend_id": 5,
        "unfriend_id": null,
        "student_id": 1
      }
    ],
    "student_id": 1,
    "student_first_name": "Paul",
    "student_last_name": "Walker",
    "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
    "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
    "class_id": 1
  },
  {
    "relationships": [
      {
        "relation_id": 2,
        "friend_id": 1,
        "unfriend_id": null,
        "student_id": 2
      },
      {
        "relation_id": 7,
        "friend_id": 3,
        "unfriend_id": null,
        "student_id": 2
      }
    ],
    "student_id": 2,
    "student_first_name": "Vin",
    "student_last_name": "Diesel",
    "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
    "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
    "class_id": 1
  },
  {
    "relationships": [
      {
        "relation_id": 8,
        "friend_id": 2,
        "unfriend_id": null,
        "student_id": 3
      }
    ],
    "student_id": 3,
    "student_first_name": "That",
    "student_last_name": "One'Guy",
    "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
    "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
    "class_id": 1
  },
  {
    "relationships": [
      {
        "relation_id": 4,
        "friend_id": null,
        "unfriend_id": 1,
        "student_id": 4
      }
    ],
    "student_id": 4,
    "student_first_name": "Not",
    "student_last_name": "Yuagin",
    "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
    "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
    "class_id": 1
  },
  {
    "relationships": [
      {
        "relation_id": 6,
        "friend_id": 1,
        "unfriend_id": null,
        "student_id": 5
      }
    ],
    "student_id": 5,
    "student_first_name": "Hei",
    "student_last_name": "Yu",
    "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
    "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
    "class_id": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: It's looking like [Through](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations) may be the answer -- I'll look into here shortly and update with progress

Comment: I'm having real issues here - I might have a very fundamental misunderstanding of how the collection object works because I can't even get a simple collection of all of a users relationships working, let alone gathering different collections depending on whether `friend_id` or `unfriend_id` is set

Comment: a) Your 'relationship' is no collection. The friends are a collection of other students. Use: friends: { collection: 'students', via: 'student_id' } and unfriends: { collection: 'students', via: 'student_id' b) This is a one-way-path: if a is friend with b, b is not yet with a, so when adding a friend, you have to to add them both (if you want to). c) you can't/shouldn't use your table 'relationship' (e.g. cause the key is wrong). Just use Students.js. To use your relationship-model, you can  use `through`, but then there's no collection in there.

Comment: I've tried that(all of it) before. Nothing shows up.

Comment: "Nothing" means "no students" or "nothing" means "no relations"? Do you just get flat students? Then this is expected. You have to populate the connections first, they are unknown (it will not use your data in your relationship-table). Maybe post your new model, I believe you tried all of it, but its hard for anyone except you and your friend-collection to diagnose it on your harddrive.

Comment: Nothing as in no data. I'll post it up as soon as I get to my home computer.

Comment: @Solarflare made an edit. What do you mean by "populate the connections" ?

Comment: Populate = you have to put data from your relationship table into the students_students table, it won't know the connections on its own.

Comment: The table's name is just `students`.

Comment: Well I think I have a tentative solution, but it's lead me to another question. I'll post the answer detailing what I did tomorrow but it's midnight and I have to be up here soon for work tomorrow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so the full thing here is pretty straight forward, I took my code above and made some changes here and there, in all honesty not thinking it would work but I got *something* which was better than the whole bunch of nothing I was getting before. It's not a perfect solution, but for right now it works well enough.

Here are the files, and what I did:

### Students.js

```
module.exports = {
    connection: 'localMysql',
    autoPK: false,
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,
    attributes: {
        student_id: {
            type: "integer",
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        student_first_name: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        student_last_name: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        student_home_phone: {
            type: 'integer'
        },
        student_guardian_email: {
            type: 'email'
        },
        class_id: {
            type: 'integer'
        },
        friends:{
            collection:'relationship',
            via:'student_id'
        },
        unfriends:{
            collection:'relationship',
            via:'student_id'
        }
    }

};
```

### Relationship.js

```
module.exports = {
    connection: 'localMysql',
    autoPK: false,
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,
    tableName:'relations',
    attributes: {
        relation_id: {
            type: 'integer',
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        student_id: {
            model:'students',
            via:'student_id'
        },
        friend_id: {
            model:'students',
            via:'student_id',
            through:'friends'
        },
        unfriend_id: {
            model:'students',
            via:'student_id',
            through:'unfriends'
        }

    }
};
```

I then added two new files to the `api/models/` directory, `Friends.js` and `Unfriends.js`, which are both pretty simple:

### Friends.js

```
module.exports = {
    connection: 'localMysql',
    schema: false,
    autoPK: false,
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,
    attributes: {
        student_id:{
            model:'students',
            via:'student_id'
        },
        friend_id:{
            model:'relationship',
            via:'friend_id'
        }
    }

};
```

### Unfriends.js

```
module.exports = {
    connection: 'localMysql',
    schema: false,
    autoPK: false,
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,
    attributes: {
        student_id:{
            model:'students',
            via:'student_id'
        },
        unfriend_id:{
            model:'relationship',
            via:'unfriend_id'
        }
    }

};
```

## The Output

The biggest thing is "am I getting the correct output" and the short answer is : no, but it's usable. I haven't gotten a Sails representation of my original query, but I have gotten close.

### output of localhost:1337/relationship

```
[
  {
    "student_id": {
      "student_id": 1,
      "student_first_name": "Paul",
      "student_last_name": "Walker",
      "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
      "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
      "class_id": 1
    },
    "friend_id": {
      "student_id": 2,
      "student_first_name": "Vin",
      "student_last_name": "Diesel",
      "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
      "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
      "class_id": 1
    },
    "relation_id": 1
  },
  {
    "student_id": {
      "student_id": 1,
      "student_first_name": "Paul",
      "student_last_name": "Walker",
      "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
      "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
      "class_id": 1
    },
    "unfriend_id": {
      "student_id": 4,
      "student_first_name": "Not",
      "student_last_name": "Yuagin",
      "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
      "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
      "class_id": 1
    },
    "relation_id": 3
  }, 
//Truncated for space
```

### output of localhost:1337/students/

```
[
  {
    "friends": [
      {
        "relation_id": 1,
        "student_id": 1,
        "friend_id": 2,
        "unfriend_id": null
      },
      {
        "relation_id": 3,
        "student_id": 1,
        "friend_id": null,
        "unfriend_id": 4
      },
      {
        "relation_id": 5,
        "student_id": 1,
        "friend_id": 5,
        "unfriend_id": null
      }
    ],
    "unfriends": [
      {
        "relation_id": 1,
        "student_id": 1,
        "friend_id": 2,
        "unfriend_id": null
      },
      {
        "relation_id": 3,
        "student_id": 1,
        "friend_id": null,
        "unfriend_id": 4
      },
      {
        "relation_id": 5,
        "student_id": 1,
        "friend_id": 5,
        "unfriend_id": null
      }
    ],
    "student_id": 1,
    "student_first_name": "Paul",
    "student_last_name": "Walker",
    "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
    "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
    "class_id": 1
  },//Truncated for length
```

Now, in `StudentsController.js` I went through and made a method, which gives me more of what I want.

### StudentsController.js

```
module.exports = {
    get:function(req,res){
        Students.find()
                        .populate('friends',{ 
                                'friend_id':{'!':null}
                        })
                        .populate('unfriends',{
                        'unfriend_id':{'!':null}
        }).exec(function(err,j){
            if(err) res.json(err);
            res.json(j);
        });
    }
};
```

### output of localhost:1337/students/get (which is closer to what I want that just /students

```
[
  {
    "friends": [
      {
        "relation_id": 1,
        "student_id": 1,
        "friend_id": 2,
        "unfriend_id": null
      },
      {
        "relation_id": 5,
        "student_id": 1,
        "friend_id": 5,
        "unfriend_id": null
      }
    ],
    "unfriends": [
      {
        "relation_id": 3,
        "student_id": 1,
        "friend_id": null,
        "unfriend_id": 4
      }
    ],
    "student_id": 1,
    "student_first_name": "Paul",
    "student_last_name": "Walker",
    "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
    "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
    "class_id": 1
  },
  {
    "friends": [
      {
        "relation_id": 2,
        "student_id": 2,
        "friend_id": 1,
        "unfriend_id": null
      },
      {
        "relation_id": 7,
        "student_id": 2,
        "friend_id": 3,
        "unfriend_id": null
      }
    ],
    "unfriends": [],
    "student_id": 2,
    "student_first_name": "Vin",
    "student_last_name": "Diesel",
    "student_home_phone": "1112223333",
    "student_guardian_email": "fake@email.com",
    "class_id": 1
  }//Truncated for length
```

Now why any of the stuff, other than the code I wrote in the controller is behaving the way it is now, I have no clue. But at least it's working.

Comment: If no one else can give me an idea, I guess I get my own bounty, which is kind of lame.